# How to groupBy in postgres with jsonb column to mimic an EAV count table?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, entity-attribute-value

I have a jsonb column that looks like this:

| Id | Data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {state: ["CA", "NY"], county:["Los Angeles"]} |
| 2 | {city: ["Kansas City"], zipCode: "12345"} |
| 3 | {state: ["CO, WA"], zipCode: "5212"} |

But I used to have a data structure like so:

| Id | Attribute | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | state | CA |
| 1 | state | NY |
| 2 | city | Kansas City |

etc...

I used to just be able to write a simple query like this:

```
SELECT attribute, value, count(*)
    FROM table
    GROUP BY attribute, value;
```

and the output would yield:

| Attribute | Value | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| county | New York County | 11 |
| city | Kansas City | 22 |
| state | CA | 15 |
| zip | 100010 | 21 |
| state | NY | 5 |

I'm trying to generate the same table above but with the jsonb table but I'm having trouble getting the desired output.

I've tried using jsonb_each_text like so:

```
with t1 as
    (select jsonb_each_text(facets) as rec from document_template_facets)
select (rec).key, sum((rec).value::int) from t1 group by (rec).key;
```

The problem is that it doesn't work for array types in my data like city, county, etc... Any way to get the arrays to be flattened in the query above to get the count to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `jsonb_each_text()` function returns rows, so it has to be in the `from` part of your query.  Do that with a `cross join lateral`.

The below query returns what you want.  The `case` within the `jsonb_array_elements_text` handles scalar values like the `zipCode` elements in your data by turning those into single-element arrays:

```
with expand_keys as (
  select id, k, a
    from tab
         cross join lateral jsonb_each(data) as j(k, a)
), expand_arrays as (
  select id, k, a, el
    from expand_keys
         cross join lateral 
           jsonb_array_elements_text(
             case jsonb_typeof(a)
               when 'array' then a
               else jsonb_build_array(a)
             end
           ) as ar(el)
)
-- select * from expand_arrays; --run this, instead, to see interim results
select k as attribute, el as value, count(*) as cnt
  from expand_arrays
 group by k, el;
```

[Fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/brK5Z5qK)

Comment: This works, thanks! Although not as performant when I was using the EAV table. Any hope to optimize/index to squeeze out better performance with this query?

Comment: You are not going to get good performance from your data model.  If your data can be modeled in relational tables, then model it in relational tables.  If what you are trying to do cannot be modeled relationally, then you are not working with data and might as well write it all down on paper pads with crayons.  Either pay the toll up front or pay it every time you run a query.